# Are all open balls in $\mathbb R^2$ with respect to any metric convex?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb R^2$,then suppose $B(x,r)$ denote open ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$.Is this set always a convex set irrespective of what $d$ is?
  Actually whenever I work with a metric in $\mathbb R^2$,I check how its open balls look,so far I have found that all of them (those I have seen) are convex sets.I do not yet know whether it is true for any metric $d$.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Also see some of the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429328/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-metric-in-mathbbrn-s-t-it-does-not-induce?rq=1, a question that appeared in the "Related" links for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true. A standard example is the metric
$$
d(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1|^p + |x_2 - y_2|^p
$$
for $p \in (0,1)$. Note there is no $p^{th}$ root. This is not locally convex.

Comment: A more general explanation can be found [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp-Raum#Lp_f%C3%BCr_p_%3C_1)

Comment: @Chiusole Does it form a metric for $p \in (0,1)$.